# WordPress : Why url header alway redirect?

Tags: wordpress

I use wordpress.When i upload to server it alway redirect to `www.ex.com/www.ex.com/wordpress`.

The right url is `www.ex.com/wordpress`.

But in my localhost it is OK. it can be with `localhost/wordpress`.
And it can go to url `www.ex.com/wordpress/wp-admin`. But it can not go to `www.ex.com/wordpress`.

Thank you.

Comment: Change the siteurl in table wp_options

Comment: Well, u start(change) your url with `/wordpress` and not with `www.ex.com/wordpress`...

Comment: try to use file search to db replace. Upload it on your live server and change the details

Comment: https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/ try this

Answer (score 0):

Add below two lines on top of your theme's function.php

```
update_option('siteurl','http://www.ex.com/wordpress');
update_option('home','http://www.ex.com/wordpress');
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Settings>General` and make sure your wordpress urls are correct. Also make sure you do not have any redirect Plugins. Also if you have any custom code of you then the wordpress won't change the urls from localhost to the correct urls, you need to do it manually. Furthermore, make sure your urls are like `http://www.yourlink.com` and not like `yourlink.com`